# How to make iPhoto library back into bundle

Tags: macos, terminal, photos.app, permission

I recently recovered from a disk failure and while most of my files are ok, I'm having trouble with my iPhoto library.

While it appears that the data fro the iPhoto library is intact in the recovered files, the library now appears as a folder rather than a bundle.  As a result, iPhoto will not recognize or open the library.

Is there any way to make it back into a bundle either from the GUI or via the Terminal?

Comment: Just wondering what version of iPhoto you are currently using/what version your backup was made from?

Comment: I was using iLife 09 when I had trouble, but now it is working with iLife 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Changed my answer.  :-)

I copied my iPhoto Library, and removed the extended attributes (a piece of metadata called com.apple.finderInfo). It then showed up as a folder rather than a proper iPhoto Library. I then fired up iPhoto holding option, and selected this folder as my iPhoto Library. It accepted it and changed the type, putting the metadata back, and all was well. I suspect this is what needs to happen in your case as well, it looks like as long as the files are there, iPhoto will do the work for you.

Old answer: I *think* you can rename it to 'iPhoto Library.bundle'.  It will then take the form of a bundle.  You can then remove the '.bundle' from the file name and it should (still) act bundle-like.

Not really sure though.

EDIT: or .app

Comment: Yes - you're right.  That changes it into a bundle, but still not something that iPhoto will read/recognize as an iPhoto library.  Any more ideas?

Comment: @dtlussier hmm.  I imagine you're selecting this folder when iPhoto asks you to select an iPhoto library, and it's just rejecting that folder as a viable option, yes?

Comment: @dtlussier You could of course create a new library and import all the photos.  I'm still trying to figure out how to associate a folder or bundle with a specific app.

Comment: @dtlussier - I copied my iPhoto Library, and removed the extended attributes (a piece of metadata called com.apple.finderInfo).  It then showed up as a folder rather than a proper iPhoto Library.  I then fired up iPhoto holding option, and selected this folder as my iPhoto Library.  It accepted it and changed the type, putting the metadata back, and all was well.  I suspect this is what needs to happen in your case as well, it looks like as long as the files are there, iPhoto will do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

1. Move or rename your existing folder that is not behaving correctly.
2. Launch iPhoto with the <kbd>Opt</kbd> key and select a new library.
3. Select the default location: `/Users/*yourname*/Pictures/iPhoto Library`
4. Quit iPhoto
5. Select the new library in Finder and then select "Show Package Contents"
6. Drag everything from your old mis-behaving folder into the new folder
7. Launch iPhoto (without <kbd>Opt</kbd>)